# Audio Autoplay not working in Chromium

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, chromium, ubuntu-mate

I have a strange problem. I am using chromium browser to open pages with audio autoplay.

Some times they work, but sometimes they won't, not until I change the volume-slider at top-right screen corner.

Comment: Open `alsamixer` and look for auto-mute property at right side.  Disable it to see if works.

Comment: Thank for reply Redbob, but I have no alsa-mixer automute mode on raspberry.